Achieving Accurate Object Detection on ESP32 Cam with Limited Resources
I'm trying to run object detection inference on an ESP32 Cam, but I'm facing challenges due to its limited processing power.
Here's what I've done so far:

Quantized a YOLOv8 model from TensorFlow to TensorFlow Lite and then to Arduino C language, but the ESP32 Cam still struggles.
Used Edge Impulse, which works reasonably well, but accuracy is low. I've tried increasing my dataset size but am limited by the platform's iteration limit.

I want to deploy an accurate object detection model locally on the ESP32 Cam with the smallest possible size.
What other techniques can I use to achieve this?
Any advice or experience with similar projects would be greatly appreciated!
